# Download data from Firebase Storage via browser

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage

I can see this list of directories in the browser. Here I can create new dirs or delete it.

[image]

But how can I download it?

Can I move all incoming data to our paid Google Cloud Platform Bucket?

And this is about paid bucket. We have this view:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use Storage in Firebase, you're actually just using a Google Cloud Storage bucket. The easiest way to work with the contents of a Cloud Storage bucket is with the [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) comment line.  When you have that installed and configured, then you can run commands to copy the contents of the bucket to and from your local machine, with [`gsutil cp`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp), for example:

```
gsutil cp -r gs://deeplabandroid.appspot.com/Values .
```